# Android Marshmallow: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user:

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a android device on which am installing my app as a System app. this App has a service and trying to start that service as

```
static void startMyService(Context context, String action) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    service.setAction(action);
    context.startService(service);
}
```

Previously I used to run my code on Android 5.1.1 and it used to work fine but now I updated it to 6.0. And now I am getting following logs.

```
Line 209209: 01-02 01:30:51.215 I/ActivityManager( 3571): Start proc 5678:com.example.myapp/1000 for broadcast com.example.myapp/.update.GenericBroadcastReceiver
Line 209239: 01-02 01:30:51.377 W/art     ( 5678): <clinit> didn't have expected constructor access flag in class com.example.myapp.update.BootStrapperService in dex file /system/app/myApp.apk
Line 209241: 01-02 01:30:51.378 W/art     ( 5678): <clinit> didn't have expected constructor access flag in class com.example.myapp.update.MyService in dex file /system/app/MyApp.apk
Line 209255: 01-02 01:30:51.393 W/art     ( 5678): <clinit> didn't have expected constructor access flag in class com.example.myapp.update.UpdateState in dex file /system/app/MyApp.apk
Line 209259: 01-02 01:30:51.400 W/ContextImpl( 5678): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1221 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 com.example.myapp.update.MyService.startServiceWithAction:301 com.example.myapp.update.GenericBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:52 
Line 209259: 01-02 01:30:51.400 W/ContextImpl( 5678): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1221 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 com.example.myapp.update.MyService.startMyService:301 com.example.myapp.update.GenericBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:52 
Line 209263: 01-02 01:30:51.408 E/PersistenceUtil( 5678): unabled to read update configuration
```

I do have constructor in my classes as below
for MyService

```
public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}
```

for BootStrapperService

```
public BootStrapperService() {
    super("BootStrapperService");
}
```

Please suggest me a way to resolve this issue

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @ColdFire My app doesn't run

Comment: I also have a system app I maintain, and see the same warning logs on both startActivity and startService Context methods, but both cases run fine for me, and my app as a whole runs fine. I've been trying to find a way to suppress these because they're annoying, but I've found nothing so far. I believe they're benign however, and there's something else in your app that's at fault for it not running.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it as a user , use an handle. 
For example :
sending broadcast message in System services

```
context.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent,UserHandle.ALL);
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt explain how to use startService  with a user handle